# ReferenceError when testing angular service with Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, esprima

I have a simple Angular.js service.  It makes use of piece of code called esprima.
Esprima is referenced in index.html like so:

...script src="https://unpkg.com/esprima@~3.1/dist/esprima.js"...

and in my code, it is referenced like so:

```
  var syntax = esprima.parse(jsCode, {tokens: true});
```

According to Esprima documentation, the CDN reference in html makes it a global variable so esprima usage in my angular.js service should work -- which it does.

However, when trying to exercise my angularjs service code from karma test, I am getting ReferenceError for 'esprima'.  I am guessing that Karma has no use for  my html file and does not pull in the Esprima package because of that.

I dont know how to "import" Esprima package in such a way that it is seen when used from the browser AND can be seen from Karma.   Sorry, I am new to this and drinking from a fire hose here. Thank you

Comment: http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  Karma.config.js file contains the "files" section where you can list any .js files you want to bring in.